# Passing Lists between Functions

Tags: python, list, function, return

**Background -** I have created 2 functions as part of a project to make API calls using values from an `entities_list` and `views_list`. The first function `def user_inputs()` asks for 2 user inputs as integer values (with v.basic error handling). The second function `def url_constructor()` iterates through the values in the 2x lists (using nested loops) and constructs URLs for my API call, before saving the URLs in the `url_list`, before a latter function will handle the API calls.

**My issue -** I am having issues accessing `entities_list` and `views_list`, specifically returning the lists from my `def user_inputs()` and having as arguments in the `def url_constructor()`

**My code -** you can see from this function, that I have attempted to `return` both lists respectively. Nothing breaks, and I can input my values into the list without issue -

```
def user_inputs():
    while True:
        try:
            entities_list = [int(x) for x in input("Entities for API Call:\n").split(', ')]
        except ValueError:
            print("---ERROR: MUST BE COMMA SEPERATED VALUES---")
            return entities_list
            continue
        break
    while True:
        try:
            views_list = [int(x) for x in input("Views for API Call:\n").split(', ')]
        except ValueError:
            print("---ERROR: MUST BE COMMA SEPERATED VALUES---")
            return views_list
            continue
        break
    return entities_list, views_list
user_inputs()
```

However, we running the following code block for my `def user_inputs()`, I get a `NameError: name 'entities_list' is not defined` -

```
def url_constructor(entities_list, views_list):
    str = 'https://some_url/{}/view{}'
    for entity in entities_list:
        for view in views_list:
            url = str.format(entity, view)
            url_list.append(ur)
url_constructor(entities_list, views_list)
```

I am not looking for someone to do my work for me, however just guide me in the right direction. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you think *continue* will do after *return* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
entities_list, views_list = user_inputs()
```

otherwise, the values returned from the user_inputs function get thrown away because they aren't assigned to anything.

Protip: you could also do:

```
url_constructor(*user_inputs())
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Answer (score 2):

Look at the example below and try to apply to your code

```
def foo():
  list_a = [5]
  list_b = [12]
  return list_a,list_b

def bar(lst):
  print(lst)

a,b = foo()
bar(a)
```